# Android Emulator UI breaks on orientation changed

Tags: android, android-emulator

Currently I have a strange issue on Android Studio 4.1 with my emulators. When I'm trying to change the orientation to landscape the ui of the emulator is completely breaking... This is how it looks like:

[image]

Has anyone an idea why this is happening? I changed the emulator performance in the AVD settings to "Software" after that it does not happen but it is very slow.

Comment: Why did you ask to [identical questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64857741/3290339) within 2 mins?

Comment: It was a network connection issue i thought the answers wasn't posted :)

Comment: Did you sort this out? I'm not able to figure out what's causing the issue and stuck with this one.