# Android Emulator UI breaks on orientation changed

Tags: android, android-emulator

Currently I have a strange issue on Android Studio 4.1 with my emulators. When I'm trying to change the orientation to landscape the ui of the emulator is completely breaking... This is how it looks like:

[image]

Has anyone an idea why this is happening? I changed the emulator performance in the AVD settings to "Software" after that it does not happen but it is very slow.

Comment: I have the same problem. Are you using macOS Big Sur?

Comment: I can confirm that setting emulator graphics options to "Software" allows the UI to respond to Orientation changes properly.

Comment: I've raised a bug report using these instructions - https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs#emulator-bugs - I'd suggest you do the same!

Comment: The display is completely broken in Landscape!

To reproduce: simply run any Android app in Landscape more (or: start in Portrait mode, and change the screen orientation to Landscape).

You can work-around the problem by turning-off the hardware display acceleration in the AVD configuration.

NB: I see this problem with all my AVDs, for different Android versions.

I've tried to raise this as a bug report from the Emulator menu, but don't seem to have the right permissions to create the bug report on the Google site!

Answer (score 7):

As already pointed out, setting emulator graphics options to "Software" helps as a temporary fix.

I would like to add that if you can't change the settings in the AVD Configuration (in my case graphics were automatic, the field was readonly), you can do that manually:

1. on AVD Manager, right-click on the desired device, then "Show on Disk"
2. look for the config.ini of the device and open it
3. change "hw.gpu.mode = auto" to "hw.gpu.mode = software"

This worked for me. Hope it helps someone else to avoid headaches.

Answer (score 5):

Hoping you are referring to emulator UI broken ,[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcpzr.png)
For me, clicking on [zoom button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu4kE.png) seems to fix the issue.