# Android studio AVD trouble with rotate

Tags: android, android-studio, avd-manager

I am using Android Studios 4.1.1 on macOS BigSur.

When I start a new AVD emulator, everything is still fine. However, if I click on the rotate buttons, the screen will have trouble. I don't know why.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

As you can see, the screen has been split in half and only the bottom screen works.

Please help me, thank you a lot!

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857741/android-emulator-ui-breaks-on-orientation-changed